# Selection changes when wrapping a string that spans across multiple tags

Tags: javascript, textselection

The `range.surroundContents` function is pretty straightforward but it doesn't work if your selection goes through multiple tags. For example, I have this string (the part in the square brackets is my selection. The brackets are not in the string)

```
This [is a <strong>simple]</strong> test
```

Lets say I want to make this selection italics. The end result would look like this:

```
This <em>is a </em><strong><em>simple</em></strong> test
```

In the range object, I replace the `startContainer` and `endContainer` after modifying their contents but that sorta resets the text selection to the start and end of the `startContainer`. How do I prevent this from happening? Try it in the snippet below. Select text starting from outside the `strong` tag and end inside it.

```js
document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
   
  const selection = window.getSelection(),
    activeRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    
  alert(activeRange.startContainer.textContent);
  alert(activeRange.endContainer.textContent);
});

document.getElementById('replace').addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const selection = window.getSelection(),
    activeRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    
  let startHTML = activeRange.startContainer.textContent,
    endHTML = activeRange.endContainer.textContent;
  startHTML = startHTML.slice(0, activeRange.startOffset)+'['+startHTML.slice(activeRange.startOffset);
  endHTML = endHTML.slice(0, activeRange.endOffset)+']'+endHTML.slice(activeRange.endOffset);
  activeRange.startContainer.replaceWith(activeRange.createContextualFragment(startHTML));  activeRange.endContainer.replaceWith(activeRange.createContextualFragment(endHTML));
});
```

```css
span{
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a <strong>simple</strong> test</p>
<br>
<span id="get">Get selection</span>
<span id="replace">Replace Selection</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my approach by removing the entire range, looping through it and modifying along the way what I needed to. The loop created the HTML of the new range which I plugged back in the same position. Hope it helps someone.

```js
document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
   
  const selection = window.getSelection(),
    activeRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    
  alert(activeRange.startContainer.textContent);
  alert(activeRange.endContainer.textContent);
});

document.getElementById('replace').addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const selection = window.getSelection(),
    activeRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    
  const rangeContents = activeRange.extractContents();

  let rangeHTML = '[';
  rangeContents.childNodes.forEach(node => {
    if(node.nodeName == '#text')
      rangeHTML += node.textContent;
    else if(node.nodeName == tagToUse)
      rangeHTML += node.innerHTML;
    else
      rangeHTML += node.outerHTML;
  });
  rangeHTML += ']';                             
  activeRange.insertNode(activeRange.createContextualFragment(rangeHTML));
});
```

```css
span{
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a <strong>simple</strong> test</p>
<br>
<span id="get">Get selection</span>
<span id="replace">Replace Selection</span>
```